# How can I center a dynamically sized div in a dynamically sized container using CSS?

Tags: css, web-applications, centering

I have a 3 level structure:

```
<div class="workingArea">
 <div class="imageContainer">
  <img class="theImage" />
 </div>
</div>
```

the "workingArea" size is determined by the browser's size (using flex in parent). The "imageContainer" size is determined by the size of the loaded image (depends on the image, each image has a different size).

I want to center the image container in the working area.

There's a catch: because the "imageContainer"'s size is determined by the image, it can be larger than the size of the working area, in which case I would like to have the center of the image to be at the center of the working area (the image should overflow to the left & right).

I've tried using flex, but it can only center it vertically, not vertically and horizontally.

[Problem simulation in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JFrCq/)

Thanks!

Comment: Fixed width(workingarea) does't expand as your need buddy.

Comment: Yea, I know. I don't want the workingArea to expand, its size is set by its parent based on the current viewport size.. I've used fixed size in JSFiddle just to make the example simpler.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to use your image as background image and position it like center-center. Even though im all for good and semantic code, if i were you, i would do so.
This way means you don't need no imageContainers or anything. Code will look just like this:

```
<div class="working_area" style="background: yellow url('http://eofdreams.com/data_images/dreams/bear/bear-05.jpg') center center no-repeat"></div>
```

If you need to be able to dynamicly change the image, you can use native JS or jQuery to manipulate the "working area".

The main minus of this solution is that you can't use image as image in browser. So no "save as" or "copy link" :C

Comment: Hey, thanks. Problem is I want to center the imageContainer, not just the image itself. The reason is I'm using canvases based on the imageContainer's size and position later on.

Comment: Well, there's another solution, it's called "JavaScript". I don't see any crossbrowser css-way to fix it.

Comment: Yea. I was hoping to avoid that, because with JS  I need to handle events such as browser resizing (which are automatically handled if I'm using CSS). Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

```
.working_area {
background-color: yellow;
background:yellow;
width:100%;
overflow:hidden;
display:table;
}

.image_container {
background:red;
display:table-cell;
position:relative;
text-align:center;

}
```

EXAMPLE :: **[WORKING FINE](http://jsfiddle.net/JFrCq/28/)**

Comment: Hey, the problem with this solution is that for me "workingArea" cannot change its size based on the content. As my mentioned in my question, it receives the size based on the viewport size, from its parent (I didn't include the actual code in the JSFiddle for simplicity's sake). Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think your bullet-proof solution would be something like this:

```
.workingArea {
    display: table;
}
.imageContainer {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
.imageContainer img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Here's the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JFrCq/30/